# How do I get rid of incorrect xmlns attributes in HTML transformed with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to transform a .html document using xslt.  The generated html for some reason has an extra xmlns attribute on the head element, and an empty xmlns attribute on the title element.

example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>foo</title></head>
  <body><h1>bar</h1><img src="baz.jpg" /></body>
</html>
```

template.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" method="html"
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/html/head">
    <head>
      <meta name="description" content="something added to the head element"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*|./node()" />
    </head>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've been testing the transformation with xsltproc and with php.

Running xsltproc:

```
$ xsltproc -html template.xsl example.html 
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="something added to the head element"></meta><title xmlns="">foo</title></head><body>
<h1>bar</h1>
<img src="baz.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Using PHP:

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DomDocument ();
$xmldoc->loadHTMLFile ("example.html");

$xsldoc = new DomDocument ();
$xsldoc->load ("template.xsl");

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsldoc);

echo $xslt->transformToXML ($xmldoc);
```

I would expect all the elements in the source document to be in the html namespace, so I don't understand why apply-templates seemingly removes the namespace from the title element.  I also don't understand why the html namespace is added to the head element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009980/xslt-using-parent-nodes-namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace is for XHTML. Therefore you should set the output mode to `xml` instead of `html` and also output the correct doctype for XHTML, or instead render as `html` and not use any namespace at all.

Note that XSLT is not quite suited for generating HTML5, but it is perfect for generating HTML 4 or XHTML if you pay some attention to details (such as which elements must or must not be empty etc.).

Comment: Changing to <xsl:output method="xml"> seems to solve most of the issues.  I still get an extra xmlns attribute on the head element, but at least it contains the correct namespace, so that will have to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case you should use a kind of identity transformation modified to remove default namespaces:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

Obviously make sure to remove this line from your XSLT:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Your final template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" method="html"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/html/head">
        <head>
            <meta name="description" content="something added to the head element"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*|./node()" />
        </head>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That seems to break elements which shouldn't get a closing tag.  In the original output you see <img src="baz.jpg"> without a closing tag, if I use the template above I get <img src="baz.jpg"></img>.

Comment: Your "original output" is not well formed. If you transform your data a fine-working XSLT processor should close all tags, even HTML tags which do not require closing tags. You should be happy about the output shown in my answer :)

Comment: Also, from the point of view of a browser, your complain is not relevant.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has the output method XHTML, which will properly emit the XHTML elements that should not be self-closing, like <img>. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xhtml-output

Comment: @Mads I think you are wrong about that. ALL correspondig HTML elements, in XHTML must be self-closing. The resultant effect we'll obtain with the suggested serialization is something like `<img />` and not `<img>`. Moreover we'll add XHTML constraints to the output, which is not what the OP is searching for.

Comment: You are correct, my comment was wrong. I meant to state that the XHTML output will do smart things with elements (e.g. it knows that it should be `<br />` and not `<br></br>`, `<script></script>` instead of `<script/>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain or reproduce your results.

Firstly, your template with match="/html/head" should not match anything in your input document, because your /html/head elements are in a namespace.

With Saxon the output I get is this, which I believe to be correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
   <head>
      <title>foo</title>
   </head>   
   <body>
      <h1>bar</h1><img src="baz.jpg"></img></body>  
</html>
```

So either you're doing something different from what you say (e.g. using a different stylesheet or a different source document from the one shown) or there's a bug in the XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: I do set a default namespace in the stylesheet as well, wouldn't that apply to the elements in the template match attribute?